# Article lead in RSS

Tags: xml, rss, standards, semantic-markup, dublin-core

What would be the most accepted way to include the **lead** (as in introductory section of a story) of an article in a RSS feed?

The [rss spec](http://cyber.law.harvard.edu/rss/rss.html) does not seem to contemplate this. Maybe the *subject* element of [Dublin Core](http://dublincore.org/documents/usageguide/elements.shtml)?

Comment: In your position, I would probably scream something about RSS being insufficient and switch to Atom, which has content and summary: http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4287.txt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you are also including the full content from the article.

This is the way I normally see it being used
http://web.resource.org/rss/1.0/modules/content/

Here's a good example of it in use.
http://feeds.feedburner.com/ommalik

Basically you put the lead in the standard RSS <description>.  then by using the content namespace you put the full article content in the <content:encoded> element.

I've also seen someone make up a <summary> tag but that's not proper.

The only dublin core I ever see is <dc:creator>

You could also generate an atom feed, https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4287